# Adding a third custom taxonomies

Tags: customization, taxonomy

where the default category to is titled 'Games'.

In the functions.php I have added this code to give each page a second category.

```
<?php
add_action('init', 'build_taxonomies', 0);

function build_taxonomies() {
    register_taxonomy('players_team', 'player', array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'label' => 'Players Team',
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => true
    ));
}
```

However I need a third added. I have duplicated the code above in "functions.php" however I get an error on website. TBH didn't think it would be just a simple copy & paste. Im looking to add a third category called "Region".

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every taxonomy you have to choose a unique name, which is used in the database. so so your new e.g. `players_region`.

```
<?php
add_action( 'init', 'build_taxonomies' );

function build_taxonomies() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'players_team', // Unique name.
        'player',       // Post type.
        array(
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'label' => 'Players Team',
            'query_var' => true,
            'rewrite' => true,
        )
    );
    register_taxonomy(
        'players_region',
        'player',
        array(
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'label' => 'Players Region',
            'query_var' => true,
            'rewrite' => true,
        )
    );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for info.

I have found the error in the functions php, as shown above was copying to much. Causing the error.

Thanks.